# Issue with the orientation of joints

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I am new to blender, although I've done some rigging in Maya. Is there a way for me to fix and reorient these joints? When the FBX was imported, it apparently made every single go straight up except the hand joints, the spine to head joints, and the knee to feet joints, every thing else is just completely wrong. Anyway to easily fix this without rerigging?[image]

Comment: See if this bit of video starting at about 40 seconds in about import problems with Mixamo characters helps: https://youtu.be/zfaskQ2BK1s?list=PLdcL5aF8ZcJux9f5Bvb1QlByiHWTK3ICP&t=42. When using the file selector to import the FBX, click the gear wheel at the top right of the file window or press 'N' to display the settings panel with the bone orientation checkbox that he mentions in the video.

Comment: @JohnEason Thank you, you are a life saver! I did that and it came out wrong, but then did "Force Connect Children" With it and it came out about as well as I think I will get it. Thanks again, really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. I haven't had that issue myself but remembered seeing that video which looked similar to your case so though it worth mentioning.